# Passing a value from JSON as a parameter to a function on table row click

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout to populate a HTML table with data from JSON, like this:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: mainData">
    <tr style="cursor:pointer;" data-bind="click: redirectDetails.bind($data)">
        <td style="width:120px;" data-bind="text: ID"></td>
        <td style="width:250px;" data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td style="width:250px;" data-bind="text: artist"></td>
        <td style="width:250px;" data-bind="text: length"></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to pass 'text: ID' value to a function that is called when you click on a table row. This is what I tried in table row:

```
<tr style="cursor:pointer;" data-bind="click: redirectDetails.bind($data)">
```

Javascript function looks like this:

```
function redirectDetails(data) {
    alert("TEST");
    //need to retrieve ID here
}
```

And this is where I'm stuck. I dont have any idea on how to pass the ID from a table row to the JS function when a user clicks on table row. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You're over engineering this problem. Knockout has a click binding. The binding will pass in the $data, and event as its arguments, below you can see just how simple it is to make it work. Make sure when working with loops you remember to back out to the parent element, OR add 'click' as a function of your object.

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.mainData = ko.observableArray([{
      ID: "1",
      name: "Mona Lisa",
      artist: "DJ Van Gogh",
      length: "3:14"
    },
    {
      ID: "2",
      name: "Move it Lisa",
      artist: "DJ Van Gogh",
      length: "1:14"
    },
    {
      ID: "3",
      name: "Macaroni Lisa",
      artist: "DJ Van Gogh",
      length: "2:14"
    },
    {
      ID: "4",
      name: "Lil' Lisa",
      artist: "DJ Van Gogh",
      length: "0:14"
    },
  ])

  self.rowClick = function(row) {
    console.log(row);
    alert(row.ID);
  }

}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: mainData">
    <tr style="cursor:pointer;" data-bind="click: $parent.rowClick">
      <td style="width:120px;" data-bind="text: ID"></td>
      <td style="width:250px;" data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td style="width:250px;" data-bind="text: artist"></td>
      <td style="width:250px;" data-bind="text: length"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```